# I cannot obtain Metadata using ADO/ADOX

Tags: visual-studio-2010, metadata, ado, adox

I am trying to obtain meta data based on a users selection. I am using the ADODB namespace to provide a connection to the database and a recordset to retrieve data from it. I have set up a connection and tested it, this works fine, but the retrieval of the data is not working.

Here is the main segment:

```
                con.Open()
                cat.ActiveConnection = con

                Select Case chk.Tag
                Case "Yes"
                    For Each modMainFunctions.tbl In cat.Tables
                        If tbl.Type = "TABLE" Then
                            frmMain.lstTables.Items.Add(tbl.Name)
                        End If
                    Next

            End Select
```

Essentially, I am checking if a particular checkbox has been selected, if it is has "i.e. case "yes" then I am trying to retrieve the Database TABLES from the provided database. However, the compiler doesn't reach the FOR loop and I cannot understand why...

modMainfunctions is my module with the main functions of my program are stored, within it I declare all my necessary variables:

```
Dim dbname As String = ""
Dim dblocation As String = Application.StartupPath
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cat As New ADOX.Catalog
Dim tbl As New ADOX.Table
Dim col As ADOX.Column
Dim view As ADOX.View
Dim key As ADOX.Key
Dim index As New ADOX.Index
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I want to obtain the meta data about a database (Please do not answer with "you need to connect to..." etc because I have already a subroutine which deals with this and it's working fine, I don't think it is a connection issue)

Comment: I would be inclined to use a schema. Is your checkbox equal to "yes" or is it true (boolean)?

Comment: I had a massive headache using GetSchema() so I wanted to use this way instead. The checkbox tag is declared yes when the checkbox is checked:

     chk.Tag = IIf(chk.Checked = True, "yes", "no")

Comment: If it is not reaching the for loop, it is something to do with the checkbox / select case. Have you tried examining the value?

Comment: The values seem to do what I expect them do to. If I breakpoint `Select case chk.tag` and highlight the tag value, it displays "yes" since I have selected that checkbox, I can step over and it will reach `Case "yes"` but it then jumps to `End select`

Comment: Can you get a count on modMainFunctions.tbl? Could it be zero?

Comment: Just to be a pain, have you tried checking chk.tag<>"yes" ie case else?

Comment: after quick watching `modMainFunctions.tbl` it shows that modMainFunctions is not a type and cannot be used as an expression. I understand this, but I cannot use `me.tbl` because modules won't allow for this. The tag property will always be NO unless it is clicked because I initiate that in the formload, there isn't a need to test a case else because there is no action to take, if you understand me

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, rather than storing this procedure in a module I simply stored it in the active form, I am unsure if this is the "best practise" but so long as my code is working as expected I'm happy. I realised that the error was because I didn't spell the world "yes" correctly... It was looking for the word "yes" and I typed "Yes" clearly the significance of thoroughly reading your code can be learnt here!